# Using xarray.plot.line with colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray, colormap

[xarray.plot.line](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.plot.line.html#xarray.plot.line) allows you to draw 2d graphs from your x-array. However the lines have a specific colormap which i don't know how to change.

I want to create the plot with a custom [ListedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html) instead of the default one.

#### Example

**I don't want the lines to be blue, orange and green**

```
data = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(2, 3),dims=('x', 'y'),coords={'x': [10, 20]})
```

>

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 3)>
array([[ 1.44058444,  0.41396068,  0.08280716],
       [ 1.0605549 , -0.97921245, -0.22373267]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 10 20

Dimensions without coordinates: y
```

>

```
data.plot.line(x="x")
```

[image: plotted lines]

since xarray.plot.line doens't take a "cmap" argument I don't know how to change the colors.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could set a color cycle, either directly via [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html) or via [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_palette.html). You need to set this a the start, before the `ax` has been created. Either way, you need a list of colors, not a colormap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @JohanC, [cycler](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html) worked!

```py
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
    
colorlist = ['c', 'm', 'y', 'k']
    
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colorlist)
    
custom_cycler = cycler(color=cmap.colors) #or simply color=colorlist
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
    
ax.set_prop_cycle(custom_cycler)
    
data = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(2, 3),dims=('x', 'y'),coords={'x': [10, 20]})
data.plot.line(ax=ax, x="x");
```

[image]